# sqlite_reset() on an INSERT with RETURNING statement rollback/cancel it

Tags: sqlite

I want to `INSERT` data in a SQLite table and do this :

```c
sqlite3_stmt *pStmt;
sqlite3_prepare(db,"INSERT INTO table(col2,col3) VALUES (?,?) RETURNING col1;",-1,&pStmt,NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < dataset_length; i++) {
    sqlite3_bind_int(pStmt,1,dataset[i].value1);
    sqlite3_bind_int(pStmt,2,dataset[i].value2);
    switch (sqlite3_step(pStmt)) {
        case SQLITE_ROW: {
            // Nice! A row has been inserted.
            dataset[i].id = sqlite3_column_int(pStmt,0);
        } break;
        case SQLITE_DONE: {
            // No results. What? Return an error.
        } return false;
        default: {
            // Return an error
        } return false;
    }
    // ↓ Problem below ↓
    sqlite3_reset(pStmt);
}
//sqlite3_cleanup(pStmt); <- Don't worry about cleanups
return true;
```

`sqlite3_step()` always returns `SQLITE_ROW` and the `RETURNING` expression works.

If I do a `SELECT` before the `sqlite3_reset()`, it returns the freshly inserted row. If I prepare and run the same query after the `sqlite3_reset()`, my table is empty, the row is vanished.

I tried without the `sqlite3_reset()` and that works, but I don't understand why and think it's due to the auto-reset feature I `OMIT` in the Windows build.

**Where I am wrong in my SQLite usage?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find out where I was wrong. SQLite mandate to call `sqlite_reset()` only after receiving an error or `SQLITE_DONE`.

In my code I only generate a `SQLITE_ROW`, but I `sqlite_reset()` before getting a `SQLITE_DONE` and it cause SQLite to somewhat "reset" the statement and rolling back changes from my point of view.

**The correct way is to after a `SQLITE_ROW`, to call `sqlite_step()` again that generate a `SQLITE_DONE` and then `sqlite_reset()`.** That means :

```c
// The way to SQLite with a RETURNING INSERT
for (...) {
    // sqlite3_bind...()
    sqlite3_step();  // Returns SQLITE_ROW
    // sqlite3_column...()
    sqlite3_step();  // Returns SQLITE_DONE
    sqlite3_reset(); // Returns SQLITE_OK
}
```

Here is below my fixed code from my question :

```c
sqlite3_stmt *pStmt;
sqlite3_prepare(db,"INSERT INTO table(col2,col3) VALUES (?,?) RETURNING col1;",-1,&pStmt,NULL);
for (int i = 0; i < dataset_length; i++) {
    sqlite3_bind_int(pStmt,1,dataset[i].value1);
    sqlite3_bind_int(pStmt,2,dataset[i].value2);
    switch (sqlite3_step(pStmt)) {
        case SQLITE_ROW: {
            // Nice! A row has been inserted.
            dataset[i].id = sqlite3_column_int(pStmt,0);
            // Generate a SQLITE_DONE
            if (sqlite3_step(pStmt) != SQLITE_DONE)
                // Something went wrong, return an error
                return false;
        } break;
        case SQLITE_DONE: {
            // No results. What? Return an error.
        } return false;
        default: {
            // Return an error
        } return false;
    }
    sqlite3_reset(pStmt);
}
//sqlite3_cleanup(pStmt); <- Don't worry about cleanups
return true;
```

Of course my code imply that there is only 1 row returned by SQLite, adapt your code if SQLite returns more. The rule is that a `sqlite_step()` must returns a `SQLITE_DONE` before doing a `sqlite_reset()`.